# How to upgrade Git in Babun

Tags: windows, git, babun

I have just installed:

https://github.com/babun/babun

in windows 8 but how do I upgrade Git to latest version?

It comes with

{ ~ }  » git --version                                                                                            ~
git version 1.7.9

I did try:

```
 pact install git-2.0.4.tar
```

Where git-2.0.4.tar is located in the current directory. I also tried to copy it too /setup but I still get this error:

```
{ ~ }  »  pact install git-2.0.4.tar
Working directory is /setup
Mirror is http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/
setup.ini taken from the cache

Installing git-2.0.4.tar
Package git-2.0.4.tar not found or ambiguous name, exiting
```

Comment: If you expect someone to help you, you should precisely describe your actual problem. What steps did you try, what kind of problems did you encounter, ...?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`pact update git`

Updated to the latest version of Git, 2.5.3, just now.

Answer (score 21):

Update your installation by using Cygwin installer:

1. Download Cygwin installer from http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe
2. Run the installer and use your .babun\cygwin directory (most likely C:\Users\your-username\.babun\cygwin) as the root install directory
3. Click through the installer. By default, it upgrades all packages.

Reinstalling git might also work:

```
pact remove git
pact install git
```

Reinstallation is quicker, but the full Cygwin upgrade is safer because all the dependencies are also upgraded automatically.

Comment: Reinstalling was sufficient for me.

Comment: Reinstalling will not work as on 18.02.2015. Please refer to https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/232
Steps provided in 'OR' worked for me.
@Juha maybe you should updated your answer accordingly.

Comment: I made the same mistake than Mr. L, maybe you should eddit your answer to warm about it.

Comment: The linked issue was marked as closed and resolved in March of 2015, so the simple reinstallation should be sufficient now.

Comment: I attempted to build git but I'm getting 'tclsh missing'.  2.8.3 vs 2.12 right now and I'm noticing some differences with advanced commands leading me back to mingw/git bash.

Comment: For anyone doubting whether the x86 version is the correct one to use with an x64 OS, yes - Babun uses the x86 version by default so install that when upgrading.

Comment: PS, this worked great (so far.) I strongly advise having a system backup in place before trying this though because you may discover that something has broken down the line.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with git after the update:

> WARNING: Git push strategy set to which is unsupported - changing to
>   'matching' ERROR: Cannot set git push.default to 'matching' - may
>   cause problems... Could not start plugin [git]

But after uninstalling it with the following command, it worked again.

```
pact remove git
```

I think now babun uses the windows installation of git..

Comment: This may be the best solution. It seems that the Babun team royally hosed the update process for (at least) git. I mean, come on...the current git version is 2.17.0 and currently ships with 2.1.something.

Comment: I second this - Pact update git does not work on latest babun. 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to update just the `git` installation using `pact update git` appears to work (at time of writing) - appropriate mirrors are found and the package is downloaded and installed successfully.

However, as @torben-vesterager pointed out on 13th March 2019, this version of `git` might cause errors. I saw the same error as he did:

```
WARNING: Git push strategy set to  which is unsupported - changing to 'matching'
ERROR: Cannot set git push.default to 'matching' - may cause problems...
Error on or near line 16, last command 'trap 'catch_err "${previous_command}" ${LINENO}' ERR';
Error on or near line 4, last command 'source "$babun_tools/git.sh"';
Could not start plugin [git]
```

Further investigation showed that this was actually because the `git` binary was not compatible with the installed version of Cygwin itself - running `git.exe` in a Windows context gave an appropriate warning about a incorrectly linked DLL (apologies for not capturing the exact message).

To resolve this properly, close all your Babun windows and run `update.bat` from the Babun home directory.  This will update Cygwin to the latest release (which `babun update` *does not do*), including a newer version of `git`.

```
» uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW a5044 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) 2019-04-30 18:04 i686 Cygwin
» git version
git version 2.21.0
```

Comment: For me babun's `update.bat` was necessary, but not sufficient. I also needed `pact invalidate && pact update git` (and some patience) to get git running again

Answer (score 0):

After git update:

```
WARNING: Git push strategy set to  which is unsupported - changing to 'matching'
ERROR: Cannot set git push.default to 'matching' - may cause problems...
Error on or near line 16, last command 'trap 'catch_err "${previous_command}" ${LINENO}' ERR';
Error on or near line 4, last command 'source "$babun_tools/git.sh"';
Could not start plugin [git]
```

Seems it's back to CygWin ... but first I'll give Windows Subsystem for Linux a try

wslgit.bat: (on x64 arch)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=%*
bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL seems to work okay ... a little tricky to use WSL's git in a Windows installed IntelliJ, but it is do-able :-)

Answer (score 0):

Many things happens by accident. This is one of them.

I enjoy using Babun but now when Babun is discontinued I knew the git version was going to become a problem (was v2.1.4).

My work computer is not connected to internet so I usually have to download complete install files and run them after transferring. No internet dependency possible.

I have Git-Bash installed but I prefer Babun terminal when I can.

Inside Babun I ran `pact update git` but I knew of course this would not work since I am not connected to internet.

This happened when I ran `pact update git`

1. pact removed git
2. pact complained that mirrors not was available (no surprise there)
3. pact gave up

Then I thought that was it for Babun now that Git was gone.

I typed `git version` and there it was `git version 2.21.0.windows.1`

Maybe not the greatest solution for everybody but it works when you have Git-Bash installed already and no internet connection.